# Convert/compare an integer to a string in C and error in a 'for' cycle

Tags: c

I have this piece of code, that doesn't work like it should. This function is connected with another one, where I ask for a city and a date. Then, after confirming both exist in the file, this function calls this new one, down below.
I know I can't compare a string with an integer, I know that is possible to convert in one another, but I don't know how to do it and if I can do it in this case. `id` is an integer, and `meteo_city_id` is a string present in a struct. I have this problem in the second part of the condition in the `if` inside the `for`.
At the same time, in the same `for`, I have `i < 152`. This is the number of rows that exist in a file I have to use. However, the user can add lines in the file so, after adding a new one, that code doesn't work anymore. So what can I replace 152 so that cycle `for` works, regardless of the number of rows that are added later?
Thanks for the help. Here is the function:

```
#define TAM_STR 100
typedef struct city_t{
char city_id[TAM_STR];
char city_name[TAM_STR];
char county_name[TAM_STR];
char district_name[TAM_STR];}    city_t;

typedef struct meteo_t{
char meteo_id[TAM_STR];
char meteo_city_id[TAM_STR];
char tempt_max[TAM_STR];
char tempt_min[TAM_STR];
char humidity[TAM_STR];
char pressure[TAM_STR];
char date[11];}   meteo_t;

city_t *read_meteo(const char *filename, size_t *len)
{
if(filename == NULL || len == NULL)
    return NULL;

FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
if(fp == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s: %s\n", "meteo.csv", strerror(errno));
    return NULL;
}
meteo_t *arr = NULL, *tmp;
*len = 0;
char line[1024];

while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fp))
{
    tmp = realloc(arr, (*len + 1) * sizeof *arr);
    if(tmp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not parse the whole file %s\n", "meteorologia.csv");
        if(*len == 0)
        {
            free(arr);
            arr = NULL;
        }
        return arr;
    }
    arr = tmp;
    sscanf(line, "%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%s", (arr[*len].meteo_id), (arr[*len].meteo_city_id), (arr[*len].tempt_max), (arr[*len].tempt_min), (arr[*len].humidity), (arr[*len].preassure), (arr[*len].date));
    (*len)++;
}
fclose(fp);
if(*len == 0)
{
    free(arr);
    arr = NULL;
}
return arr;
}

void search_meteo_by_city_by_date(meteo_t *meteo, size_t len, const char *city, const int id, const char *date){

bool find = false;

if(meteo == NULL || city == NULL || id == NULL || date == NULL) {
    printf("ERROR");
}

for(size_t i = 0; i < 152; ++i) {
    if (strcasecmp(date, meteo[i].date) == 0 && id == meteo[i].meteo_city_id) {
        find = true;
        printf("Information for: %s in %s \nMaximum Temperature: %s ºC\nMinimum Temperature: %s ºC\nHumidity: %s \nPressure: %s hPa\n\n\n", city, date, meteo[i].tempt_max, meteo[i].tempt_min, meteo[i].humidity, meteo[i].preassure);
    }
}
if(find == false) {
    printf("No results were found for: %s\n", city);
}
}
void search_date_by_city() {

size_t cities_len;
city_t *cities = read_cities("cities.csv", &cities_len);
char local[100];
char date[100];

// error
if(cities == NULL) {
    printf("ERROR");
}

printf("City: ");    
scanf("%[^\n]%*c", local);  

int id = search_for_city_by_name(cities, &cities_len, cidade);

if(id == -1) {
    printf("That city doesn't exist\n");    
    return;
}

printf("Date: ");    
scanf("%[^\n]%*c", date);  

size_t meteo_len;
meteo_t *meteo = read_meteo("meteo.csv", &meteo_len);

if(meteo == NULL) {
    printf("ERROR");
}

search_meteo_by_city_by_date(meteo, &meteo_len, local, id, date);
```

}

The file cities.csv has 152 rows and 4 columns, such as

```
id,city,county,district
```

The file meteo.csv has 152 rows and 7 cloumns, such as

```
meteo_id,meteo_city_id,tempt_max,tempt_min,humidity,pressure,date
```

Comment: This is not how you format code.

Comment: please provide the MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I swear I thought I copied all the code... Sorry... It's complete now

Comment: The posted code does not compile.  Amongst many other errors, the needed `#include` statements are missing.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) separate code blocks ( `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` ) via a single blank line.  3) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent)

Comment: the posted code is NOT a [mcve].  Amongst other things, there is no `main()` function.

Comment: for flexibility, it is best to separate the definition of a struct from a `typedef` of that struct.

Comment: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers. I.E,.11, 100, 152, 1024 'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: where the function: `read_meteo()` is defined, the return type is `city_t*` however, where that function is called, the returned type is `metro_t*`.  This is an error that needs to be corrected

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.   in the current scenario, any returned value other than 7 indicates an error occurred.  2) when using the input format specifiers `%[...]` and/or `%s`,  Always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer because those specifiers always append a NUL byte.  This will avoid any possibility of a buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the function: `search_meteo_by_city_by_date()` is expecting the parameter `len` to contain the actual number of entries, However, where that function is being called, what is being passed is the ADDRESS of the variable that contains the actual number of entries.

Suggest replace this:

```
search_meteo_by_city_by_date(meteo, &meteo_len, local, id, date);
```

with this:

```
search_meteo_by_city_by_date(meteo, meteo_len, local, id, date);
```

which is passing the contents of `metro_len` rather than the address of `metro_len`

then replace this:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < 152; ++i)
```

with

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
```

Answer (score 1):

So you need to know the number of lines in a file. Can you simply count the number of line feeds  or carriage returns ?

I can’t see your implementation of read_meteo but I presume you can add something in there that counts the number of lines in the file.

Also, atoi() might be useful to convert a string number to an int.

Answer (score 1):

## The larger solution

**Always compile with all warnings enabled.**

If you had done so, you would have caught things like these:

```
In function ‘read_meteo’:
test.c:51:16: warning: return from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
         return arr;
                ^~~

 error: ‘meteo_t {aka struct meteo_t}’ has no member named ‘preassure’;
     did you mean ‘pressure’?
 sscanf(line, "%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%s",
(arr[*len].meteo_id), (arr[*len].meteo_city_id), (arr[*len].tempt_max),
(arr[*len].tempt_min), (arr[*len].humidity), (arr[*len].preassure),
(arr[*len].date));

warning: comparison between pointer and integer
 if (strcasecmp(date, meteo[i].date) == 0 && id == meteo[i].meteo_city_id) {
                                                ^~
warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
meteo_t *meteo = read_meteo("meteo.csv", &meteo_len);
              ^~~~~~~~~~
warning: passing argument 2 of ‘search_meteo_by_city_by_date’ 
makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
search_meteo_by_city_by_date(meteo, &meteo_len, local, id, date);
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~
note: expected ‘size_t {aka long unsigned int}’ but argument 
    is of type ‘size_t * {aka long unsigned int *}’
void search_meteo_by_city_by_date(meteo_t *meteo, size_t len, 
                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~
    const char *city, const int id, const char *date){
```

## The *not-so-right-after-all* solution

Simply replace `152` with `len`. Apparently you already have an array index counter in there:

```
meteo_t *meteo = read_meteo("meteo.csv", &meteo_len);
if (meteo == NULL) {
    printf("ERROR");
    // YOU SHOULD ALSO EXIT IF YOU EVER ENTER HERE.
}
search_meteo_by_city_by_date(meteo, &meteo_len, cidade, id, date);
```

The above, as @user3629249 pointed out, is logically correct **but formally incorrect** because the parameter being passed is **not** the value (which is probably 152, so correct) but **its address**, which is almost surely NOT 152, and therefore wildly incorrect. And that's why when you apply this solution you  get a crash.

If you had activated compiler warnings, this error wouldn't have been there, and if *I* had, I believe I would have given the right (*but still not complete! Look at those problems above!*) answer. Since neither of us used warnings, **you and I both ended up being wrong**. So: *use compiler warnings*.

Comment: I already tried that, the program compiled but after displaying the information, the run fails... I will post the function read_meteo, it will be easier that way, I think...

Comment: Yes, it looks like you have a different problem too. Can you verify that meteolen is 152 before invoking searchmeteobycity?

Comment: I know that the file has 152 rows, but I don't know if I have a variable that contains the number of rows. I though it was len, but it doesn't seem so...

Comment: this is not the correct answer as it does not address the root of the problem.  Where the root of the problem is the call to `search_meteo_by_city_by_date()` is passing an address rather than the contents of the 'len' variable